# java swing addactionlistener JButton

Tags: java, swing, hashmap, jbutton, jtextfield

I have a `JPanel` where a `JTextFiled` exists. I want to show the information belongs to a hashmap collection in this `JTextFiled`.

My hashmap collection is:  `HashMap<String,Job>jobs = new HashMap < String,Job>();`

My method in the other class (Branch) has the method for getting all the Jobs:

```
    public String getAllJobs()
 {       
        String result_jobs;
        result_jobs = " ";

        Collection<Job> jobValues = jobs.values();
        Iterator<Job> Jobiter =  jobValues.iterator();

       while(Jobiter .hasNext())
       {
       Job jo = Jobiter.next();
       result_jobs += jo.toString()+ '\n' ; 
       }

       return result_jobs; 

    }
```

In this `JTextFiled`, it should be entered key value of hashmap indicating Customer Name which is declared as String in the `HashMap` collection shown  above.    When it is pressed  Add Job `JButton`, the information belongs to the hashmap collection is listed in the `JTextFiled`.

The figures are below;

[image]

[image]

I have tried to write down the method of `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`.

Since I am very new in Java, I have difficulty to write down this method.

```
 private class AddJobButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { }
      }
```

*EDITED: 
if there was a menu like the one below and by selecting the "Add Job" menu item;
How would the codes change?*

[image]

I would appreciate if you suggest/recommend any examples, methodoligies or anything.
 Thanks in advance,
 Serb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You need a `JTextArea` to display the the information from `Job`
- Also what I would recommend is to override the `toString()` method in the `Job` class. Something like

  ```
  public String toString() {
      return "Job No: " + jobNum +
             "\nCustomer: " + customer +
             "\nCredit Limit: " + creditLimit
      ....
  }
  ```
- Then in the `actionPerformed` all you have to do, is check the value in the text field, then get the value from the map and display it in the text area.

  ```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      String customer = textField.getText();
      if (map.containsKey(customer)) {
           jta.append(String.valueOf(map.get(customer)));
           jta.append("\n***********************\n\n");
      }
  }
  ```

---

Run this example. to see what I mean. Just type in one of the names from the map and press the button

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestMap {

    private JTextArea jta = new JTextArea(15, 30);
    private JTextField jtf = new JTextField(30);
    private JButton button = new JButton("Show Job");
    private Map<String, Job> map;

    public TestMap() {
        map = getMap();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(jta, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(jtf, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!"".equals(jtf.getText())) {
                    String customer = jtf.getText();
                    if (map.containsKey(customer)) {
                        jta.append(String.valueOf(map.get(customer)));
                        jta.append("\n***********************\n\n");
                    }
                    jtf.setText("");
                }
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Map<String, Job> getMap() {
        Map<String, Job> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("Paul", new Job(100, "Paul", 10000.00));
        map.put("Jim", new Job(101, "Jim", 20000.00));
        map.put("John", new Job(102, "John", 30000.00));
        map.put("Sean", new Job(103, "Sean", 40000.00));
        map.put("Shane", new Job(104, "Shane", 50000.00));
        map.put("Mike", new Job(105, "Mike", 60000.00));

        return map;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestMap();
            }
        });
    }
}

class Job {

    int jobNo;
    String customer;
    double creditLimit;

    public Job(int jobNo, String customer, double creditLimit) {
        this.jobNo = jobNo;
        this.customer = customer;
        this.creditLimit = creditLimit;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Job No: " + jobNo
                + "\nCustomer: " + customer
                + "\nCredit Limit: " + creditLimit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Totally solving the issue, Thanks a lot.

Comment: *EDITED: 
if there was a menu like the one below and by selecting the "Add Job" menu item;
How would the codes change?*

Comment: Firstly, thanks a lot...and,Can you see the menu items? I should apply your code by selecting the "Add Job" menu item...How should I approach to this?

Comment: @Serb I think the question should be transferred to its own separate question

Comment: I posted my question in a seperate question